# HDFS Data Write Process for different disk size nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

We have 10 node HDFS (Hadoop - 2.6, cloudera - 5.8) cluster, and 4 are of disk size - 10 TB and 6 node of disk size - 3TB. In that case, Disk is constantly getting full on small size disk nodes, however the disk is free available on high disk size nodes.

I tried to understand, how namenode writes data/block to different disk size nodes. whether it is equally divided or some percentage of data getting written.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy.  By default this is set to `round-robin` but since you have an asymmetric disk setup you should change it to `available space`.

[image]

You can also fine tune disk usage with the other two `choosing` properties.

For more information see:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_dn_storage_balancing.html